# PivotTable.js - pivot() always return count() values

Tags: pivot, pivottable.js

I am using PivotTable.js and I am trying to use pivot() to create a table as follows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var tpl = $.pivotUtilities.aggregatorTemplates;

            $.getJSON("9_Response.json", function(mps) {
                $("#output").pivot(mps, {
                    derivedAttributes: {
                        "Market": function(mp) {
                            return mp["market"];
                        },
                        "Year": function(mp) {
                            return mp["stYear"];
                        }
                    },
                    aggregators: {
                        "Sum1": function() { return tpl.sum()(["totSale"])}
                    },
                    rows: ["Market"],
                    cols: ["Year"],
                    aggregatorName: "Sum1",
                    rendererName: "Table"
                });
            });
         });
    </script>
```

When I use PivotUI() it works fine but I would like to create a static table only, without UI (without drag n' drop attributes, renderers and aggregator selectors). I need just the table.
With pivot() I am getting always sums of the record count, not the sums of the field values.
Could you please advise of how to resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

I'm the author of the PivotTable.js and I've posted an example for how to do this here: http://nicolas.kruchten.com/pivottable/examples/simple_agg.html

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the use of `aggregator` is understood.